# Selecting classes with nth-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm looking for help with using the nth-child CSS selector. If you take a look at my HTML...

```
<div id="report">
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="b">B</div>
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="b">B</div>
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="a">A</div>
</div>
```

...I have a row of letters like this:

```
AAAABAAAABAAA
```

I want to only show the first B and hide the others, however I cannot seem to select the classes as I expect. When I try to use:

```
.b:nth-child(1){
    display: block;
}

.b:nth-child(n+2){
    display: none;
}
```

It doesn't work and I have to select it using (5) to just get the first B.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SrM9T/1/

Comment: the `nth-child` is not applied after the class selector, it always selects the element at the passed index with respect to the parent...

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QpfL9/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny with all due respect you can add these in a single comment or an answer instead of spamming comments…

Comment: Please stop suggesting to use a whole javascript framework to do something that can be done with CSS.

Comment: I'm afraid there really is not way of doing this in CSS alone. What you would want to use is :nth-of-type but you can only use this on elements and not classes. If you made all the b's span's then you could get it to work.

Comment: @ColinBacon I'm afraid there is.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SrM9T/15/ try this if u know which nthchild u want to select

Comment: @adamjld You can also use `.b:nth-child(2n-1)` to select what you want, but that's admittedly a more round-about way of doing it :-P

Comment: Related: [CSS selector for first element with class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class) (I originally marked this a dupe, but on closer inspection it's not quite one, although still related)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This does not require javascript

```
.b ~ .b{
    display:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KYAj8/1/

**General sibling combinator**

> The general sibling combinator selector is very similar to the adjacent sibling combinator selector The difference is that that the element being selected doesn't need immediately succeed the first element, but can appear anywhere after it.

[More info](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

Comment: This is nice, you can chain it too eg `.b:none`, `.b~.b:block`, `.b~.b~.b:none`

Comment: It always surprises me how obscure the `~` combinator is, given that even IE7 has partial support for it so it's been available to use for quite some time. Note that this answer assumes the default `display: block` for `div` elements which obviates the need for a general `.b` selector - if you're looking to apply arbitrary styles to the first element, you'll need to apply them using the general rule, then undo them using the sibling rule, as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107).

Comment: @BoltClock the answer originally had `display block`.

Answer (score 2):

this is your jquery

```
$('.b').not('.b:eq(0)').hide();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/SrM9T/9/)

Comment: are you guys mad. did you check the fiddle .

Comment: I think this is still a valid answer.. since the OP tagged jquery in his question

Comment: yes. he tagged this question in jquery . so we can give a solution in jquery.

Comment: Please don't suggest that people use javascript, let alone a whole javascript framework, to solve a CSS issue that can be solved with CSS

Comment: that fine. but they should take care while tagging question. they shouldn't tag jquery when they don't want answer in that.
because here people believe in downvoting more than checking answer.

Comment: They don't know any better. You do: edit the question.

Comment: @NigelAngel Don't assume that the jQuery framework isn't already being used, either. OP tagged it in the question himself, therefore it's a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

By Using Jquery

```
$('.b:not(div:first)').hide();
```

Here i put the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htoniv/Hubzv/) demo